# Как в Linux Ubuntu 10.* показывать только 1-го пользователя?

Tags: unix, ubuntu

Вообщем есть > 2 пользователей в системе,Как руками сделать так, чтобы был виден только 1 пользователь для общих дел, а остальные были скрытыми.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, в каком смысле показывать, где и кому?

Comment: при заходе в ос, и в "пользователи и группы".Дабы избежать излишней любопытности со стороны других пользователей.Воплощение этого видел, а реализацию нет.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
sudo gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory --type Boolean --set /apps/gdm/simple-greeter/disable_user_list True
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то Вас интересует именно это: [изменение экрана входа в систему](http://ubuntumaster.ru/ekran_ubuntu.html).